# How to get SSIS connection which is defined using a custom connection manager

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-connection-manager

I am trying to edit a SSIS package from code using ManagedDTS dlls (and others) and I need to access one of the connections defined in the package in order to re-map the columns in one of the source components. The problem is that this connection is created with a custom connection manager and it is therefore not recognized, when the package is loaded. 
The code should be something like this:

```
Application app = new Application();
Package package = app.LoadPackage("packagepath", null);
var customConnection = package.Connections["customConnectionManager"];
```

Where the customConnection is the connection that I am looking for.

I am able to create a new package with this type of connection but as soon the package is saved and reloaded, I don't have access to it. 
The custom connection manager is in GAC and can be normally used in VS SSDT. When I make a new package in add the connection "customConnectionManager" is works as intended.

Is there a way to access connections in the SSIS packages that are made with custom connection managers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I managed to solve the problem and the reason why the connection was not recognized is because the application had the "Prefer 32 bit" compile option enabled. Looks like the custom connection manager was only 64-bit version.